# Handle "ok" button on mobile keyboard JQUERY select form input

Tags: jquery, forms, select, input, keycode

i'm almost finished developing my mobile application using html/css/JS and JQUERY but i'm facing some problems with forms

As for now, i have to choose the option in my "select", then click "ok" on the keyboard and then click on the submit button.
I would like to catch the event when the user clicks on the "ok" button on top right of the keyboard (see link below for the image, cant put it here until 10 of reputation), has anyone got any idea about how to achieve that? 
For simple inputs, i figured it out with the keycode == 13 but not this one... 
Thank you
Valentin

[example of OK button](http://i62.tinypic.com/2cor3nn.png)

EDIT : the select works now, but i can't handle the click on one of the radio buttons, i tried with .change(), even some JSfiddle examples but still not working..
Here is the code :

HTML PART :

```
<div id="vendreLouer">
                            <fieldset class="vendreLouer" data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal">
                                <div id="radioB">
                                    <h6><label id="label_vendreLouer">Vous souhaitez :</label></h6>
                                    <input name="radio-choice-h-2" class="radio1" id="radio-choice-h-2a" value="Vendre" type="radio">
                                    <label for="radio-choice-h-2a">Vendre</label>
                                    <input name="radio-choice-h-2" class="radio1" id="radio-choice-h-2b" value="Louer" type="radio">
                                    <label for="radio-choice-h-2b">Louer</label>
                                </div>
                            </fieldset>
                        </div>
```

I tried to attach the .change(function(){}) on both .vendreLouer AND #vendreLouer but nothing happens

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using `.change()` ?  http://api.jquery.com/change/ . It should work for what you are trying to achieve.

EDIT:
For the radios you can do something like this:

```
$('#radioButtonID_HERE').change(function() {           
//#radio-choice-h-2a .... in your case
    if($(this).is(':checked'))  {
          //do something if checked
    } else {                              
        //do something else if it's not
    }
});
```

Comment: I tried to use change() for an entire day to do the same thing but with radio button from JQUERY... IMPOSSIBLE to make it work BTW but i'll try for the select right now thanks

Comment: The .change() worked well for the select thank you lansen, I'm updating the question right away with my problem about the radio button and .change() with some code, if you could check it it would be great !

Comment: Just tried your solution, but it still doesn't work... I'm having the impression that once the page is fully loaded, it won't go in the change function... I've tried anything i found on the web it's really weird, with other simple radio buttons (not jquery mobile ones), it worked better but i must use those radio buttons from JQUERY unfortunately !